# overwrite tsconfig.json from the package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have React app install a third-party package using Typsecript, running my react app current get an error message like below:

```
Class constructor Name cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I did try to decare a variable with new for that, does not work.

so I dig deeper turn out the third package we use to extend of component have this setting in the tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
    }
}
```

Is any way I can overwrite this setting in my current react app since I don't can't change that package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that this is possible, since if you did not create the app with the typescript template `react-scripts` will not use typescript. You have two options here: use `cra` to make a new app using the `--template typescript` option and copy your code, or run `npm run eject` or `yarn eject` to expose the configuration files for webpack and add the loader yourself, although this is risky because it risks messing up the project configurations.